# How to find the common path of a list of paths?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list with paths that use '/' as delimiter, for example:

```
aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
aaa/bbb/ccceee
aaa/bbb/ccc/fff
```

How can I write a function in python that would return
the string 'aaa/bbb/'?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @HaifengZhang I don't care what he tried. I care that he had a problem and someone solved his problem (and mine). However, it's a bit more complicated than that, when you consider cross platform requirements. In python3.5, there's os.path.commonpath (_not_ commonprefix, which is deceiving in behavior). I ended up porting commonpath from 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am totally new to python (started yesterday), but this is what I came up with:

```python
paths = [ 'aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee', 'aaa/bbb/ccceee/fff', 'aaa/bbb/ddd/eee', 'aaa/bbb/' ]

def get_common_path(paths):
    common = []
    common_size = -1

    for p in paths:
        s = p.split('/')
        s.pop()
        if common_size == -1:
            common_size = len(s)
            common = s
            continue
        while common_size > 0 and s[0:common_size] != common:
            common_size -= 1
            common.pop()

    return '/'.join(common) + '/'

common_path = get_common_path(paths)
print 'Common path = \'{}\'; length = {}'.format(common_path, len(common_path))
```

which outputs:

```
Common path = 'aaa/bbb/'; length = 8
```

Answer (score 4):

[Commonpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath) does that for you:

```
import os

paths = ["aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd",
         "aaa/bbb/ccceee", 
         "aaa/bbb/ccc/fff"]

os.path.commonpath(paths)
```

Answer (score -2):

Newline-separated input like you posted:

```
paths = """
aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
aaa/bbb/ccceee
aaa/bbb/ccc/fff
"""
```

A cryptic, hacky mix of list comprehension, `zip()`, `set()` and `join()`

```
common = "".join([y[0] for y in zip(*[x for x in paths.split("\n") if any(x)]) if len(set(y)) == 1])
print common[:common.rfind("/")+1]
```